# PHP: create and run PostGres Procedure (BEGIN ... END) with binding parameters

Tags: php, postgresql

I am using Postgres with PHP, I have two dependent queries as below:

```
INSERT INTO tab2 
           SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE  col1 = $1 AND  col2 IS NOT NULL;

DELETE FROM tab1 WHERE  col1 = $1 AND  col2  IS NOT NULL  ;
```

I want these both to run or none of them. So I created below code block:

```
DO $$ 
   BEGIN 
       INSERT INTO tab2 
           SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE  col1 = $1 AND  col2  IS NOT NULL  ;
       DELETE FROM tab1 WHERE  col1 = $1 AND  col2  IS NOT NULL  ;
   END$$
```

But this is not working and giving below error:

**ERROR:** bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0

**PHP Code:**

```
$result = pg_query_params($pg_con_write,$query_PG,array($Param1));
```

I think I can't use Bind Parameters in this way... So please suggest the best possible way to do so...

Comment: It's a bit confusing how you're running this code; can you [edit] to show us the PHP you're using? I'm also not sure a `DO` block is the right tool for the job here; maybe you just need a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT TRANSACTION`?

Comment: @IMSoP added the PHP line

Comment: DO blocks do not accept parameters. As commented above, just use a transaction to get the all-or-nothing effect (aka atomicity).

Comment: @DanielVérité Will [the answer given below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53814858/8494462) not do the same

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $$ is the issue, you should rewrite your query like:

```
BEGIN; 
   INSERT INTO tab2 
       SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE  col1 = $1 AND  col2  IS NOT NULL;
   DELETE FROM tab1 WHERE  col1 = $1 AND  col2  IS NOT NULL;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: will it ensure atomicity of the queries?

Comment: @ShivamSharma yes of course, thats what transactions do.